# Django :how can i show the content of post of particular user

Tags: python, django

hi am working on a project where user-added the post onto the site and driver check his post and give him offer ( price) to ship their load  .when the driver submits the post(price) ....at the admin level the selected post and which driver adds the price is working properly, however when the same user logged in (which added the post earlier)and want to see the price of his post-offer by a particular driver. so how can I show to the front end with filtration of the particular user?

this is my user post model

```
class Loader_post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name="Loader")
    pick_up_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    destination_station = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    sender_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    receiver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


def __str__(self):
     return self.user.username

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("Loader:my_job", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

here is the price added to the post

```
class price(models.Model):
    my_post = models.ForeignKey(Loader_post, related_name='prices',on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
     null=True, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, default='')
    driver_price = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    approved_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("Driver:Driverview")

def __str__(self):
    return self.driver_price
```

this is the view of the user post(views.py)

```
class Loader_post_view(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    form_class = forms.Loader_post_form
    model = Loader_post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("Loader:my_job")



def form_valid(self, form):
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

and this is the view of added price o particular post

```
@login_required
 def add_price_to_post(request, pk):
     post = get_object_or_404(Loader_post, pk=pk)
     user = request.user
     if request.method == "POST":
        form = price_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        ps = form.save(commit=False)
        ps.user = request.user
        ps.status = True
        ps.save()
        ps.my_post.add(post)
        return redirect('Driver:Driverview')
    else:
        form = price_form()
return render(request, 'price_form.html', {'form': form})
```

now how can I show at the front-end of particular logged in user-added price to the post

[image: driver logged side where driver add price to the post]

[image: add price]

[image: admin level]

Comment: If I understood correct, you want to show all prices of a post to post owner when he/she logs in. You can do it by looping over `loader_post.prices.all` in template.

Comment: yes u find correct sir ...can u elaborate more..means I did what u say ...but maybe ur code fill correct .. can u give code for that....like which model should use ....,i want show prices along with loader id and more about driver

Comment: You can access all prices using `related manager`. In your case `loader_post` is your post and `loader_post.prices.all` contains all prices to that post. Your template will be something like this - `{% for price in loader_post.prices.all %} {{ price.driver_name }} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: sir r u sure ..... i think it will show all the prices of all post,... no particular user logged in  prices

Comment: Let me explain it more, you can get all post related to logged in user by `request.user.Loader.all`. So finally `{% for loader_post in request.user.Loader.all %} {% for price in loader_post.prices.all %} {{ price.driver_name }} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}`. So the first forloop will give you all post related to loggedin user and inner forloop will give you the prices associated to each post

Comment: yes it works sir ....buut more thing  what if i want to show loader id and Loader_post details ...when i  use in template like sender_name which i used in model loader_post ...sender name is not displaying4

Comment: You can access all model fields like `loader_post.sender_name`, `loader_post.phone_number` or whatever field you want to show. It has to be inside first forloop as loader_post it iterator.